# How to format the output in CSV file when outputting

Tags: r, csv

So I am trying to get an output in csv file but I am having trouble formatting as per my need.

## My Code

```
method.metric   <- mmetric(testCenScal[[course_name]], method.pred, c("RMSE", "R2", "MAE", "COR"))
write.table(method.metric, "metric.csv", sep = ",", col.names = T, append = T)
```

## Current Output

```
"x"
"MAE",0.636059658390333
"RMSE",0.814405873704867
"COR",0.581863604936215
"R2",0.338565254749368
"x"
"MAE",0.636059658390333
"RMSE",0.814405873704867
"COR",0.581863604936215
"R2",0.338565254749368
"x"
"RMSE",0.869309100173694
"R2",0.356594555638249
"MAE",0.653084184175849
"COR",0.597155386510286
"x"
"RMSE",0.869309100173694
"R2",0.356594555638249
"MAE",0.653084184175849
"COR",0.597155386510286
```

It would be nice if I could format this output into something like:

```
RMSE   R2    MAE   COR  param1     param2
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseA  Blackboost
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseB  Blackboost
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseC  Blackboost
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseD  Blackboost
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseE  Blackboost
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseA  Rpart
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseB  Rpart
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseC  Rpart
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseD  Rpart
0.89  0.35  0.65  0.59  courseE  Rpart
```

I dont know what is "x" and where is it coming from, I guess I don't have the column name mentioned therefore it prints default as "x"?

I have this code in a function so I am passing two parameters one is the method and another is the target field. I would like to print those while appending it to a CSV file.

If I type `dput(method.metric)`

I get output as:

```
structure(c(0.869309100173694, 0.356594555638249, 0.653084184175849, 
0.597155386510286), .Names = c("RMSE", "R2", "MAE", "COR"))
```

I already tried using the code `write.csv(method.metric, file ="metric.csv", row.names=FALSE, eol=",", append=T)` but it did not help much.

I will try to work on what you said formatting in R using cbind and other functions. If I get the output in above format, I will be able to create graphs with ease as I have lot of predictive model results being output.

Comment: Add output of `dput(method.metric)` to your post. It is better to prettify the output (merge, append, cbind, rbind, etc.) within R, before saving as a csv, also there is a `write.csv` function.

Comment: @zx8754 I have updated my question with dput(method.metric)

Comment: This will convert named vector to a data.frame: `data.frame(as.list(method.metric))`, then I am assuming you are writing to a csv in a loop, so the first write.csv should have col.names = TRUE, the rest FALSE. Or use `do.call(rbind, lapply(..)` and write.csv once.